# Misuse of inverse function theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Let $U=\{\binom{u}{v}\in \mathbb{R}^2|0<v<u\}$. Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^2, f(u,v)=(u+v,uv)$. Show that $f$ has a **global** reverse function, find $g=f^{-1}$ and its domain.

---

**Not a valid solution**: For any $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$
\\  Df(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1\\ 
 v& u
\end{pmatrix} \ne0 \Leftrightarrow u\ne v  \ 
$$
then $Df(u,v)$ is reversable for any $(u,v)\in U$. Thus, $\forall (u,v)\in U$,
$$
\\   g(u,v)=\frac{\operatorname{adj}(Df(u,v))}{\operatorname{det}(Df(u,v))}=\frac{1}{u-v}\cdot   \begin{pmatrix}
u & -1 \\
-v & 1 \end{pmatrix} \
$$ I understand this is not the solution, but I don't understand where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've found the inverse of $Df$, not the inverse of $f$.